# jquery add class to appended images

Tags: jquery, class, append

I am trying to add images to the main div dynamically and give them the class of "card".  I've tried a couple of ways but none seem to add the class when I inspect the element.

here's I've tried:

```
collection.forEach(function(pack){
        pack.forEach(function(info){
            if (info.golden === true){
                $('.main').append('<img src="' + info.imgGold + '"></img>');    
                } else {
                $('.main').append('<img src="' + info.img + '"></img>');
                }           
        });
        $('img').addClass('card');
        $('.main').append('<hr></hr>');
    });
```

I also tried:

```
collection.forEach(function(pack){
        pack.forEach(function(info){
            var image;
            var img = $('<img src="' + image + '"></img>');
            if (info.golden === true){
                image = info.imgGold;
                img.appendTo('.main').addClass('card');                     
                } else {
                image = info.img;
                img.appendTo('.main').addClass('card');

                }           
        });
        $('.main').append('<hr></hr>');
    });`
```

I also tried:

```
$('.main').append('<img class="card" src="' + info.img + '"></img>');

$('.main).append($("<div/>",{
  html : "<img src='" + image + "'/>",
  class : 'card'
}));
```

I also experimented using

```
.attr('class', 'card');
```

CSS:

```
.card{
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 200px;  
}
.card:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Hearthstone Pack Simulator</h1>
                <form>
                <select name="sets" id="sets">
                    <option value="Classic">Classic</option>
                    <option value="Goblins vs Gnomes">Goblins vs Gnomes</option>
                    <option value="Journey to Un'Goro">Journey to Un'Goro</option>
                    <option value="Mean Streets of Gadgetzan">Mean Streets of Gadgetzan</option>
                        <option value="The Grand Tournament">The Grand Tournament</option>
                        <option value="Whispers of the Old Gods">Whispers of the Old Gods</option>
                </select>
                    <select name="no of packs" id="nop">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2 - $2.99</option>
                        <option value="7">7 - $9.99</option>
                        <option value="15">15 - $19.99</option>
                        <option value="40">40 - $49.99</option>
                    </select>
                <input type="submit" id="submit">
                    <input type="submit" id="reset" value="Reset">
                </form>
        </header>
        <div class="tab_a">
            <h3>Collection</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab_b">
            <h3>Current Packs</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab_c">
            <h3>Extra Cards</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
        </div>
        <div class="main">
        </div>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: whats the issue then? have you checked does it appended? do inspect

Comment: the class isn't being applied to the images.

Comment: any console error? your code is right. may be you missed class card related functionality

Comment: no errors in the console no.

Comment: add your html code

Comment: when i inspect the element the class isn't applied.  this is the css  .card{
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 200px; 
}
.card:hover{
 opacity: 0.8;
}

Comment: If you step through are you getting into the `foreach` loop and into the `if` block? Or the images are appearing but not with the class?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to put the `card` class on this div: `<div class="main">` and then adding `.card img {}` to your stylesheet and it would apply the style to all of the images within that div.

Comment: that's what i was using previously.  it was working.  now i want to add different images that wont have the .card class

Comment: never mind. i figured it out.  it's triggering on the wrong event.  can I delete my question? lol

Comment: Or just put an edit and explain what your issue was in case people see something similar?

Comment: haha yeah.  the answer is to write your code in the function where you want it to happen.